# changing color in flushleft in deedy-resume

Tags: xetex, color, deedy-resume

[image]I'm trying to change the color of the heading lines ( for example the name and contact info in the title should a different color for each line of the headings). 
And unfortunately it doesn't work as I'm expecting it to.

Firstly, I'm working with the following template:
https://www.overleaf.com/articles/rishabh-cv-v3/chvmptzhvfnb

As you can see in the picture, 2 is a different color, using \color, however, i'm unable to change the color for 1.

Second, in the .cls file, there is a section which deals with the "namesection", however, as this is a modified template, it does not make use of that section.

Third, I have tried the following:

-`\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{some bold and colored text}}`, which did not work in the `flushleft`.
-I also tried `\color{blue}`inside and outside `flushleft`
-finally i tried `\leavevmode\color{red} text`

I believe the pertinent section is the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{deedy-resume} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{flushleft}
\Huge \textbf{RISHABH URVESH SHAH}\\*
\begin{small}

\vspace{-7mm}
\textbf{\urlstyle{same}{\footnotesize \\ \url{http://aqes.cee.illinois.edu} | \url{hiwater.org}} | \href{mailto:rushah2@illinois.edu}{\underline} rushah2@illinois.edu | +1 (217)-819-6377 
}
\end{small}
\end{flushleft}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Shall is till upload a screenshot?

Comment: yes, please mark in the screenshot, what you want to change. Are you open to use the other template?

Comment: Please find attached the screenshot. Also, I am open to using the other template, however, I do hope that it's left-justified. Also, I also want to understand why `\color` doesn't work in this context

Comment: Thank you, once again, for your very thorough answer. Sorry that i have been asking many questions lately. I will try your answer and then let you know.

Comment: You are welcome, see my update for bolded `Work Address` in your title ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best way to get what you want is to redefine command `\namesection`, for example like this:

```
\renewcommand{\namesection}[7]{ % Defines the command for the main heading
\flushleft 
{
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
\\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
}
\flushleft 
{ % Center the contact information
\color{headings} % Use the headings color
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Bold}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textcolor{red}{#3} 
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textcolor{blue}{#4} \\
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Bold}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #5
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #6 \\
{\footnotesize #7} \\
} % Contact information font
%\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
%\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}
```

With this redefinition you can add 7 parameters to `\namesection` like

```
\namesection{RISHABH}{URVESH SHAH}%
{Work Address:}{4140 NCEL MC-250, 205 N Mathews Ave, Urbana IL 61801, USA}
{Home Address:}{107 E Springfield Ave, Apt. 217, Champaign IL 61820, USA}
{{\urlstyle{same}\url{http://aqes.cee.illinois.edu} | \url{hiwater.org}} | \href{mailto:rushah2@illinois.edu}{rushah2@illinois.edu} | +1 (217)-819-6377}
```

Please see that I added your `\flushleft`, I changed the font for the firstname and the fontsize and I added one example showing how to change the color of printed datas (see that bolded font in included in font name!):

```
\textcolor{red}{#3}
```

and

```
\textcolor{blue}{#4}
```

I also deleted the closing rule for the title ...

Now you can work with that and change it to what you need ...

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{deedy-resume} 
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\namesection}[7]{ % Defines the command for the main heading
\flushleft 
{
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
\\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
}
\flushleft 
{ % Center the contact information
\color{headings} % Use the headings color
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Bold}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textcolor{red}{#3} 
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textcolor{blue}{#4} \\
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Bold}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #5
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont #6 \\
{\footnotesize #7} \\
} % Contact information font
%\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}


\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\namesection{RISHABH}{URVESH SHAH}%
{Work Address:}{4140 NCEL MC-250, 205 N Mathews Ave, Urbana IL 61801, USA}
{Home Address:}{107 E Springfield Ave, Apt. 217, Champaign IL 61820, USA}
{{\urlstyle{same}\url{http://aqes.cee.illinois.edu} | \url{hiwater.org}} | \href{mailto:rushah2@illinois.edu}{rushah2@illinois.edu} | +1 (217)-819-6377}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LEFT COLUMN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.29\textwidth} 

\section{Education} 

\subsection{University of Illinois}
\subsection{at Urbana-Champaign}

\descript{M.S. Civil and Environmental Engineering}
\location{Expected Aug 2015 | GPA: 3.91}

\sectionspace 

\subsection{Gujarat Technological}
\subsection{University}

\descript{B.E. Environmental Engineering}
\location{June 2013 | GPA: 8.67/10.00}

\sectionspace 

\sectionspace 

\section{Coursework}

\subsection{Graduate}

Air Quality Engineering \\
Air Quality Modeling \\
Atmospheric Meteorology \\
Aerosol Sampling and Analysis \\
Environmental Transport Modeling \\
Water Chemistry


\sectionspace 

\subsection{Undergraduate}


Wastewater Treatment Process Design \\
Environmental Impact Assessment \\
Environmental Legislation and Audit \\
Occupational Health and Safety \\
Waste Management \\
Project Management \\
Fundaments of Automobile Engineering \\
Conventional Power Engineering \\

\sectionspace 

\section{Skills}

\subsection{Computer}
Aerosol Instrument Manager \textbullet{} LabVIEW \textbullet{} MATLAB \textbullet{} AERMOD \textbullet{} Engineering Equation Solver \textbullet{}
\\ WRPLOT View \textbullet{} MINEQL+ \textbullet{} ALOHA \textbullet{} MARPLOT

\sectionspace

\subsection{Certificates}
\textbullet{}Energy and Sustainability Engineering | Jan 2015| University of Illinois, Urbana-Champaign
\textbullet{}Certified LabVIEW Associate Developer (CLAD) | Jan 2015 | National Instruments
\sectionspace 

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   RIGHT COLUMN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 

\section{Experience}

\runsubsection{Graduate Research Assistant} |\descript{\small Dept. of Civil and Environmental Engineering, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign}

\location{Expected May 2014 – Aug 2015 | Urbana, IL}
\vspace{\topsep} 
\begin{tightitemize}
\item Advised by Dr. Mark J. Rood and Dr. Tami C. Bond.\\
\item Conducting laboratory experiments to characterize the optical properties and cloud condensation nuclei (CCN) activity of biomass-burning aerosol in tandem with atmospherically relevant tracer gas, ozone. Extensive use of aerosol sampling and measurement equipment.\\
\item Research funded by the US Department of Energy. 
\end{tightitemize}

\sectionspace 

\runsubsection{Graduate Teaching Assistant} |\descript{\small Dept. of Natural Resources and Environmental Sciences, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign}

\location{Jan 2014 – May 2014 | Urbana, IL}
\begin{tightitemize}
\item Assistant to Dr. Bethany B. Cutts.\\
\item Tasks included leading weekly discussion sessions, weekly course planning, holding office hours and grading assignments. Worked under Dr. Bethany Cutts.
\end{tightitemize}

\sectionspace 

\runsubsection{Vocational Trainee} |\descript{\small Environmental Control Unit, Gujarat Narmada-Valley Fertilizers Pvt. Ltd. (GNFC)}

\location{June 2012 | Bharuch, Gujarat, India}
\begin{tightitemize}
\item Stationed at the Nitro-Effluent and Common Effluent Treatment Plant (NETP and CETP) for treating combined effluent streams from various chemical manufacturing units of GNFC.
\end{tightitemize}

\sectionspace 

\section{Project Experience}

\descript{Automotive air pollution and its control by catalytic converters}

\location{Fall 2013 | Independent Study | University of Illinois}
A study of the formation of air pollutants in an internal combustion engine, role and limitations of catalytic converters in controlling emissions
\sectionspace 

\descript{Modeling of increase in SO\textsubscript{2} concentrations due to proposed erection of stacks}

\location{Fall 2013 | Coursework Project | University of Illinois}
Modeling ambient SO\textsubscript{2} emissions around proposed site of stack erection using AERMOD, Breeze 3D Analyst and WRPLOT ViewTM software. 

\sectionspace 

\descript{Mitigation response following a cyclohexane spill}

\location{Fall 2013 | Coursework Project | University of Illinois}
Modeling the behaviour of a hypothetical cyclohexane spill using computer software, viz. ALOHA, MARPLOT and CAMEO Chemicals and to develop an emergency response plan to be followed in such scenario.

\sectionspace 

\section{Presentations} 

\textbullet{}\location{\color{darkgray} Poster: "Hygroscopicity and CCN Activity of Biomass-burning aerosol"}
{\footnotesize Mar 2015 | US Department of Energy: Atmospheric System Research Meeting | Vienna VA\\}
\textbullet{}\location{\color{darkgray} Poster: "Measuring CCN activity of Organic Carbon with Ammonia Aging"}
{\footnotesize Apr 2014 | Environmental Engineering and Science Symposium | Champaign IL}
\sectionspace 

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]